# Why does the SSDictCursor use up to 2,5 GB of RAM when I try to fetch 1,5 million rows, while the SSCursor uses just 650 MB of RAM?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

When I try to fetch 1,5 Million rows from MySQL table by Python script with MySQLdb, I receive “Out OF Memory” error on my server.

After debugging I got this info.

1. with SSCoursor or default cursor it uses only 650 MB of RAM
2. with SSDictCursor it uses more than 2,5 GB of RAM and causes “Out of Memory” error

Is that normal ??? If no, then how can I decrease Memory usage for SSDictCursor?

Python version 2.7.12

```
  try:
    print "About to connect to db."
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = int(conf['sshtunnel']['fwdport'])
    if rs_env == 'private':
      host = conf['db'][data_src]['private']['dbhost']
      port = 3306
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
      host   = host,
      port   = port,
      user   = conf['db'][data_src][rs_env]['dbuser'],
      passwd = conf['db'][data_src][rs_env]['dbpass'],
      db     = conf['db'][data_src]['db'],
      # cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
      # use ssdictcursore for fetch rows in server side without out of memory error
      cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor)
  except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

  c = db.cursor()
  query = "SELECT * FROM ....."

  c.execute(query)
  print "\n EXECUTED"

  # fetch rows one by one for prevent outh of memory error
  results = []
  while True:
    row = c.fetchone()
    if row == None:
      break
    results.append(row)

  print "Fetched {0} records from DB.".format(str(len(results)))
  c.close()
  db.close()
```

1. In the first case, I use SSCursor (cursorclass =
   MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor) and it uses only 650MB of RAM.
2. In the second case, I use SSDictCursor (cursorclass =
   MySQLdb.cursors.SSDictCursor) and it uses more than 2,5GB of RAM.

Comment: I suggest you show some source code in the question for the two scenarios you describe.

Comment: @codeape I edited my question and added code

Comment: Great! Could you also show the code where you execute a query? What do you do with the returned rows?

Comment: @codeape I just fetch and append it to list, nothing else, and it takes up to 2,5GB of RAM

Comment: The idea is to fetch data from the DB, and then to put it to a new file and upload this file to another server, but I can’t continue coding because of the “out of memory” issue

Comment: OK I see. But do you need to append the rows to a list and then save at the very end? If you write each row as you iterate through the rows returned (and not store rows in list), then the Python interpreter can reclaim the memory used by each row when they are no longer referenced.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I believe that your solution will fix the OOM issue. There are a few other solutions, for example, I can add LIMIT and OFFSET to query, or just use  SSCursor instead of SSDictCursor, BUT I want to understand why does it use up to 2,5 GB of RAM?

Comment: How many rows? Number of colums? Datatypes used?

Comment: My query returns 7 columns. 5 columns type is INT and 2 columns type is TINYINT. 
Total rows count is 1.480.456